# printf: not enough arguments passed for format string

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, printf

The system keeps telling me that I do not have enough arguments to format the string, I am also getting a

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)   line 1 error
```

I do not know what this means. please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


 Main() {

    int score, sum = 0;
    printf("Enter a test score (-1 to quit):");
    scanf_s("%i", &score);

    while (score != -1) {
        sum = sum + score;
        printf("Enter a test score (-1 to quit):");
        scanf_s("%i", &score);
    }
    printf("\n(The sum of the scores is): %i\n");
        system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Isn't the error message self explanatory? `printf("\n(The sum of the scores is): %i\n");` requires one more parameter to specify where the `%i` comes from:  `printf("\n(The sum of the scores is): %i\n", sum);`

Comment: For the second error, `Main` needs to be `main` as C is case sensitive. And you may as well declare it completely: `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, int **argv)`

Comment: Every C book should include these basics. You should read one. In addition to the documentation of functions you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the execution of every C program starts with main() function and the error is in line 1.

So replace `Main()` with `main()` as C is case sensitive.

Now `scanf_s()` required one more argument as Buffer size. User is allowed to give the input upto that size only.

For example, `scanf_s("%i",&score,2);`

For more info about scanf_s, [click here](http://faculty.edcc.edu/paul.bladek/CS131/scanf_s.htm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434735/difference-between-scanf-and-scanf-s)

And if you will replace `scanf_s()` with `scanf()`, it will work too.

Hope it will help!