# Trying to print out how many characters are in the input string

Tags: c, string

I think the reason it keeps crashing is related to my scan statement, but I have tried multiple different was.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char str[100], i;

  printf("Enter a string: ");
  scanf_s("%s", &str);

  for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i);

  printf("Length of string: %d", i);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is `scanf_s()`? It's not in the man pages.

Comment: `scanf_s("%s", &str);` should be `scanf_s("%s", str);`. i.e. drop the `&`.

Comment: @Blacksilver: It is part of the standard. Albeit optional. Man-pages are not authoritative.

Comment: @Blacksilver scanf_s is a safer form of scan and if i drop the & the program still crashes.

Comment: Read the documentation of functions you use! Your code invokes undefined behaviour. Said that: use the normal `scanf` and provide the max. field-width.

Comment: if i use scan in visual studio the program will not run. I have to use scanf_s @Olaf

Comment: Thank you @user3121023 that fixed it.

Comment: @Crowe: You will get a warning, which is against the standard. You can silence this (read the help! Better use a C standard compliant compiler, MSVC has even more severe issues. Anyway, call functions with the correct arguments! A good compiler should already warn about the wrong call. To repeat: read the documentation.

Comment: @Olaf `scanf_s` requires a size argument for each `%c` and `%s` format, to follow each usual address argument. IMO that makes it even more tricky than the standard `scanf` function, and so not at all "safer".

Comment: @WeatherVane: It also requires one for the `[` conversion specifier. And that's why I recommended to use a compliant compiler, as `scanf` has not been removed from the standard. `scanf_s` has advantages for RLE encoded character sets like UTF16 and UTF8, though.

Comment: @Olaf did I say otherwise? I would prefer to read an input with `fgets` and then the next processing choices are wider - `sscanf` or `strtok` or examing the input *ad hoc*.

Answer (score 0):

There are safer and more robust ways to do what you are trying to do, but i assume this is a learning experience so try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

# define MAX_CHARS   100

int main( void )
{
   char str[MAX_CHARS];
   int i;    /* i should be an integer */


   printf("Enter a string (less than %d characters) : ", MAX_CHARS );

   /* scanf( "%s", str );  */   /* do not use &str, str is already a pointer */

   fgets(str, MAX_CHARS - 1, stdin );

   for ( i = 0; (i < MAX_CHARS) && ( str[i] != '\0' ); ++i ) ;

   printf("Length of string: %d\n", i);

   return 0;
}
```

using `scanf("%s", str);` will only pick up the characters prior to a space,
so if your string is `hello world` then the contents of **str** will only be `hello`.

and if using scanf then if you enter more than MAX_CHARS, or in your case 100 characters, then you will have an overflow which is bad.  Using `fgets` is safer, but will include the `\n` character in **str**.

normally you hit the `enter` key to signal that is the end of input,
however you can hit  control-d to signal end of file, and this will work with `fgets` and the contents of **str** will not have the `\n` character at the end.  On my system I have to hit ctrl-d twice.

Comment: Thank you! @ron ill try this

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of solving this problem 
 use `gets(str);` instead of `scanf_s("%s", &str);`

and use `strlen(str)` instead of loop;
But you need to add a header file for it which is `<string.h>`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  char str[100];
  int  i;

  printf("Enter a string: ");
  gets(str);

  i=strlen(str);

  printf("Length of string: %d", i);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Noooooooooo... Don't use gets. the man page literally starts with `Never use this function; see BUGS`. It's only use is codegolf.

Answer (score -1):

1) <strike>`scanf_s()` is not a thing.</strike> <strike>Wait, it is?</strike> Oh, It's a visual studio thing. Okay.
2) you passed `&str` instead of `str` (this is why you crashed)

```
int main(){
    char str[100];
    int i;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){};

    printf("Length of string: %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hang on - [`scanf_s` *is* a thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434735/difference-between-scanf-and-scanf-s).

Comment: I really don't appreciate how condescending you are. scanf_s is a thing, I do the the & to read in the string. I'm using visual studio. A Microsoft based IDE which uses scanf_s as a safer form of scan.

Comment: I didn't know it was a thing until *just now* when @RadLexus told me. Sorry.

Comment: @Blacksilver - So, I feel, you don't qualify to write this answer. Please delete your answer!

Comment: It works now. all i did was     scanf_s("%s", &str, 100)

Comment: Read the standard! While man-pages are nice to use, they don't define what is standard and what not.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful: You are free to downvote such answers, but please don't press writers to delete something (maybe you could have phrased this a bit more friendly). And yes, I agree this is not a good answer, especially as it now includes a new question.

Comment: I've edited my question to try to be less condescending. Sorry!