# Double being returned as jumbled numbers

Tags: c

New to programming in general, creating a program in C with VisualStudio that would take a floating point from the user and return if it is negative or not, then get it as an integer, and finally return the first digit of the integer. Code looks something like this:

```
double extractDigit1(x){
     double userFloatValue = x;
     (userFloatValue >= 0) ? printf(" %f is a positive value.", userFloatValue) :
                             printf(" %f is a negative value.", userFloatValue);
}

int main(){
     double userValue;
     scanf_s("%lf", &userValue);
     extractDigit1(userValue);
}
```

Entering 1234.345 gets me:

```
"1202590843.000000 is a positive value."
```

instead of:

```
"1234.345 is a positive value."
```

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]

Comment: If you don't specify the type of the function argument, it is assumed to be `int`. You should change your function to `void extractDigit1(double x)`

Comment: I'm not sure `double extractDigit1(x)` is what you intended to write, because here `x` will be an integer.

Comment: This code should'nt compile. What IDE/Compiler/environnment/OS do you use?

Comment: @Jabberwocky it is valid C89 garbage... (less the includes). The only platform that has `scanf_s` is... _________.

Comment: Try to enable all warnings and read them! ... in `gcc` you may use: `gcc  -Wall source.c`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala right. Thanks, I completely forgot about such garbage, I've never used it and I haven't seen it in the last 25 years.

Comment: @Jabberwocky just tested with gcc, and `-std=c89' no warnings if the include is there.

Comment: You have reason ... @AnttiHaapala. :(

Comment: Using a ternary operator instead of an `if` statement is an interesting stylistic choice.  And I use "interesting" euphemistically.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root problem is

- `double extractDigit1(x)` is not a correct function prototype, it should be `double extractDigit1(double x)`

  Wiht what your write, x was considered as `int` which is not compatible with the rest of code.

Note that

- Your functions return nothing whereas their prototypes tell so

  It's an undefined behavior that can lead to anything

Finally

- You use `scanf_s` function, with is almost like `scanf` but handle strings differently and is less portable (see [Difference between scanf and scanf_s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21434735/1212012)). I advice you not to use it.

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double extractDigit1(double x){
    double userFloatValue = x;
    (userFloatValue >= 0) ? 
        printf(" %f is a positive value.", userFloatValue) :
        printf(" %f is a negative value.", userFloatValue);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
   double userValue;
   scanf("%lf", &userValue);
   extractDigit1(userValue);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked. I'll accept your answer in like 6 mins.

Comment: `scanf_s` is a microsoft function that take more parameters than `scanf`. In `scanf_s`, buffer sizes have to be specified to prevent buffer overflow. So functions are not interchangeable.

Comment: IIRC, more parameters are required only for format specfiers like `%[`, `%c` and `%s`, right? How is the `scanf_s` a problem in the OP's case?

Comment: @Spikatrix [Indeed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019)!

Comment: But then how is that a problem as your answer states?

Comment: @Spikatrix It is not, I was persuaded that `scanf_s` was requiring the buffer size in all cases. The root error is just the `x` variable defined as an `int` since not typed. That said, I discourage the `scanf_s` usage.

Comment: Yes but your answer stating it as a problem "_You mix `scanf_s` and `scanf`: you called the first like the second_" is not right as the OP's `scanf_s` is perfectly valid

Comment: Again you're right, I was correcting when you tell me ;-)

Answer (score -2):

```
double userFloatValue = x;
int my_var = (int)userFloatValue ;
         (userFloatValue >= 0) ? printf(" %d is a positive value.",   my_var ) :
                                 printf(" %d is a negative value.",  my_var ) ;
```

Use  scanf rather  than scanf_s 
scanf("%f", &a);

Comment: then get it as an integer don't you think it should be int