# if statement in C

Tags: c, if-statement

Going through some entry level C programming and having trouble with this seemingly very simple logical operator. The first if statement is skipped if you enter last name Paul. Also trying to understand buffer size when using scanf_s.

```
int main(){

    char name[25];

    printf("what is your last name? ");
    printf("(Please capitalize the first letter!)\n");
    scanf_s(" %s", name, 2); 

    if ((name[0] >= 'P') && (name[0] <= 'S'))

    {
        printf("You must go to room 232 for your tickets\n ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You can get your tickets in the lobby\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question contains some statements but not an actual question. Please [edit] your question and write what you need help with. Read the documentation of `scanf_s`.

Comment: I can't reproduce that using `scanf(" %s', name)`. It works as expected. You should check your `scanf_s` call.

Comment: Strictly speaking letters are not necessarily placed in alphabetic order in the symbol table and there may be gaps between them. The only symbols guaranteed to be placed adjacently are `'0'` to `'9'`.

Comment: Also, perhaps needless to say, include stdio.h and compile with a standard C compiler.

Comment: Whether your characters are sequential depends on the character set in use. ASCII is probably in use on 95%+ of systems in use today, see [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) Older [EBCDIC](http://www.lookuptables.com/ebcdic_scancodes.php) is not sequential throughout the character ranges, but is in increasing order throughout -- thankfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `scanf_s(" %s", name, 2);` statement, the third argument here specifies the size of the character array (`name`) into which to read the given response. I'm not sure why you have given `2` as that size, when you have declared, in the `char name[25];` line, that you have an *actual* size of `25`.

However, with that `2` value, the read will fail if you type in more than one character (try just giving "P" as input, and you will enter the `if` block).

From the [documentation for scanf_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) (bolding mine):

> The buffer size includes the terminal null. You can use a width
> specification field to ensure the token that's read in fits into the
> buffer. **When a token is too large to fit, nothing is written to the
> buffer** unless there's a width specification.

Also, it is *always* a good idea to check the return value from `scanf_s` (and related functions), to make sure the read was successful! Adding a few check as shown in the snippet below will show you what's going on, with various different inputs:

```c
//...
    int n = scanf_s(" %s", name, 2);
    printf("Items read = %d; Name given is: %s ...\n", n, name);
//...
```

With this, when I enter "Paul" as input, I see the following:

```
what is your last name? (Please capitalize the first letter!)
Paul
Items read = 0; Name given is:  ...
You can get your tickets in the lobby
```

---

Note: On the debate about whether or not to use `scanf_s` in place of `scanf` (as the Microsoft compiler advises), see here: [Difference between scanf and scanf_s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21434735/10871073).

Comment: Got it. Changed my buffer size and it worked and also tried 'P'. Visual Stdio is telling me scanf is deprecated so I need to use scanf_s. Should your buffer size match your variable size?

Comment: You can use the `_countof` macro (defined in `<stdlib.h>`) to use the *actual* size of your character buffer(s), like this, in your case: `int n = scanf_s(" %s", name, (unsigned)_countof(name));`.

Comment: As to whether to use `scanf` or `scanf_s` ... that's a big debate (especially here on S.O.)! There are **many** folks who will scream at you for following Microsoft's 'advice', and others who will say it's OK (or even good). But that's not my call.

Comment: The *field-width* `1` would also make it usable for a 1 character read, e.g. `int n = scanf_s(" %1s", name, 2);`. Or for a one character read `*name = getchar();` and `name[1] = 0;` would nul-terminate.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Actually (I just tried) a field width of `2` still fails! One would need a field width of `1`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hehe - All good C/C++ coders indulge in a bit of self-slapping from time to time. (Should be incorporated into the Standards.)