# Taking an input through array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I learnt about the concept of array of pointers and ragged arrays, but i'm not able to understand why my code isn't working.

```html
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int* b[10] ;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            scanf_s("%d", (*(b+i)+j));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code, so I will just post the corrected one with explanations:

```
int *b[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // you need to allocate memory to each pointer inside your array as well
    // I have allocated for 3, since you scan 3 integers
    b[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
         // use scanf like this, you need the address not the value of variable you are scanning
         scanf("%d", (*(b + i) + j));
     }
 }
```

You need to include the header file for `malloc`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Also, don't forget to `free` the dynamically allocated memory later to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guide , well i was indeed missing out on the indirection operator , but didn't know about allocation of memory of pointer

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted to close it. @yugsharma1711

Comment: Actually  it needs 5 minutes for marking , i will definitely do it

Answer (score 1):

scanf_s takes an address of a variable but you are passing a value.  Doesn't your compiler complain?  If not, bump up the warning/errors levels.  Others already told you that you need to allocate memory for the array pointers to point at.  If this was production code remember to free().

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an array of pointers:

```
int* b[10];
```

you need to allocate memory for each of those pointers, namely:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    b[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
 }
```

From [Difference between scanf and scanf_s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434735/difference-between-scanf-and-scanf-s) one can read:

> **scanf** originally just reads whatever console input you type and assign
> it to a type of variable.
> (..)
> **scanf_s** has an argument(parameter) where you can specify the buffer size and actually control the limit of the input so you don't crash the whole building.

Therefore, what you need is `scanf`, hence change your code from:

```
scanf_s("%d", (*(b+i)+j));
```

to

```
scanf("%d", (*(b+i)+j));
```

You should also check the returning value of the `scanf` function, and free the memory of the dynamically allocated array.

An example of a full running code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   int array_size = 3;
   int* b[array_size] ;
   // Allocate memory for my array
   for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        b[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
   
   int scanf_value = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
           if(scanf("%d", &b[i][j]) != 1){
                while(getchar()!='\n'); // clean the input buffer
                printf("Invalid Input! Add just numbers\n");
                j--;
           }
       }
    
   // print those elements
   for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           printf("%d ",b[i][j]);
    
   // lets free the memory
   for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        free(b[i]);
    
   return 0;
}
```