# uninitialized local variable 'num' used?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter your number \n");
    scanf_s("%d", num);
    printf("Your number is %d", num);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When i build the above code in VS2013 it gives me following error :

error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'num' used ??
Whhat would be the reason for this ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the &:

```
scanf_s("%d", &num);
```

`scanf` expect a pointer, so it was reading the value of `num` to find the address to write the user input (and num was not initialized, that's why the compiler raise a warning). But what you really meant is the address of num itself.

Comment: btw what is `_s`? I don't know..

Comment: Is the "secure" version of scanf, that can prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: I also dont know "scanf_s" i wrote "scanf" the intellisense suggested me to make it scanf_s otherwise it was giving and error.

Comment: okay fede thats great :)

Comment: Interesting OP is using a "secure" version of `scanf()` on an uninitialized variable yet does not check the return value.

Comment: @chux OP is using secure version in insecure way :P

Comment: @SaadAhmed For a short explanation about scanf_s look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9986940/1025899